# simple jump to another page

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to after click on my button i go to another page. but i just get error.
this is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime_paradise_t1);

    Button list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setText("List");
    list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AnimeParadiseT1.this, View.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in `View` class :

```
public class View extends Activity{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.list);
     }
}
```

it's so strange. look at my logCat too :

```
08-29 00:12:32.910: D/AndroidRuntime(1582): Shutting down VM
08-29 00:12:32.910: W/dalvikvm(1582): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40203560)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.animeparadise/android.view.View}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.animeparadise.AnimeParadiseT1$1.onClick(AnimeParadiseT1.java:29)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 00:12:34.061: I/Process(1582): Sending signal. PID: 1582 SIG: 9
```

and one thing more. i just define `View` class as an `Activity`.

Comment: Also change the name of your activity to something like ViewActivity instead of View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 08-29 00:12:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.animeparadise/**android.view.View**};

Check your `import` statements. `View` is an existing class in Android (`android.view.View`). You probably need to use the full name of your `View` class (e.g., `com.animeparadise.View.class` or whatever) when you create your `Intent`.

Also, as others have suggested, you should rename your activity to avoid this confusion and adhere to the common practice of ending the class name with the word `Activity` (e.g., `ViewActivity`).

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]

`android.view.View` already exists. That is what is going wrong (hence the 'android.view.View' part in the error): the class creating the intent is including the wrong `View` class.

Simply rename your `View` class to whatever. And press CTRL-SHIFT-O to fix your imports ;)

(And ensure your AndroidManifest.xml includes `<activity android:name=".WhateverClassNameYouChose"/>` in the `<application>` section.

Comment: tnx for remind me about name of activity in application. i speak about `.` part. so, it seems i just can accept one answer, if it could , i accept your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Add your class to your AndroidManifest.xml file, like

```
 <activity
            android:name=".View"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**OR**

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: Redundant answer. You should have added it as comment.

Comment: Yeah, my bet, I edited my answer because this is not the problem. Looking at the error more closely, it is actually looking for the wrong 'View' class

Answer (score 1):

you should add something like this to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name = ".View"
    android:label="my new Activity" >
</activity>
```

Also i suggest you to change the name of your acivity, because View is a very import class on Android ([View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)).

Hope it helps!

Comment: tnx for reply. i added it before.

Answer (score 0):

Put a habbit of reading Logcat carefully, The error is,

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.animeparadise/android.view.View}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This is because you havnt declared your activity in the android manifest file,

write this code in your android manifest file,

```
<activity
            android:name=".View"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If it doesnt works, try changing the name of activity, because View is a predefined class and the name of two classes might cause the conflict..